# Displaying a custom twig template with Sonata and Symfony2

Tags: templates, symfony, twig, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

For my need, I'm planning to add a custom column to a entity list.
I've written this inside the configureListFields :

```
->add('_action', 'actions', array(
            'actions' => array(
                'code' => array('template' => 'BOBAdminBundle:test:custom.html.twig'),
            )
        ))
```

My twig :

```
<img src="{{ asset('bundles/sonataadmin/famfamfam/delete.png') }}"  />
```

It works.
Problem : I don't know why :S, since I've just copy/paste the code from somewhere.
I figured out than the '_action' determined the name of the column. But what if I want to change it ?
Where does this 'actions' name come from ? Where can I change it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The _action is used to **add custom actions for the list items**. Like edit and delete which are set by default. Here is a full documentation:

### List actions

You can set actions for the list items by adding an ‘**_action**’ field in *configureListFields*:

```
<?php
    $listMapper->add('_action', 'actions', array(
    'actions' => array(
        'view' => array(),
        'edit' => array(),
    )
))
```

Edit and delete actions are enabled in the default configuration. You can add your own! Default template file is: *SonataAdminBundle:CRUD:list_*action*[ACTION_NAME].html.twig*

You can specify your own by setting up the ‘**template**’ option like so:

```
<?php
$listMapper->add('_action', 'actions', array(
    'actions' => array(
        'view' => array(),
        'edit' => array(),
        'delete' => array('template' => 'MyBundle:MyController:my_partial.html.twig'),
    )
))
```

Comment: Hmhmh OK, I get the concept there :-). Thanks.